# Cant get HTML rows childrens length using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get particular rows children length using jquery but i am getting all html element of that particular rows children.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="title"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my jquery code goes.

```
console.log($("#title").parent().parent().find('tr').eq(3).html())
```

I want to get third rows children length. Pls help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, as `th` can be direct child of `table`, First correct you HTML

Answer (score 4):

Simplify your selector using [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like

```
$('tr:eq(2)').children().length
```

```js
alert($('tr:eq(2)').children().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="title"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

Having `th` elements not wrapped in a `tr` is invalid HTML. Additionally, some browsers will make up for this by auto-wrapping them. Therefore, you need to adjust your HTML to properly target the '3rd' row.

I have removed the invalid

```
<th></th>
<th></th>
```

from the snippet. But the OP needs to take account of this to achieve his goals.

Note, as an alternative, the OP can put a in the desired row and target like

```
$('.target-row').children().length
```

```js
alert($('.target-row').children().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="title"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <tr class="target-row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: actually second rows children length will be 6 but u r getting 2.How

Comment: @htoniv, I dont know, I am looking into it!

Comment: @htoniv Because browser is wrapping `<th></th> <th></th>`  in a `tr`, Thats what you get with invalid HTML

Comment: @htoniv, for some reason, it is wrapping the <th> in a <tr>!

Comment: @Satpal, definately unexpected. Looking up why this happens?

Comment: @AmmarCSE, this is expected behavior. also notice `tbody` tag

Comment: @Satpal, it seems I have to put nowrap on th. trying it out

Comment: @AmmarCSE, Certainly OP has to get rid of invalid HTML. You don't have to do anything

Comment: @Satpal, thanks for your insight/help. Updated my answer

Comment: I dont want to do without `th`.

Comment: @htoniv, see my answer for a different approach. However, still, you should not have unwrapped <th>! :)

Answer (score 0):

`eq(2)` will get the third `tr`.

`children().length` will get no. of tds inside third `tr`.

```
console.log($("#title").closest('table').find('tr').eq(2).children().length)
```

Comment: Please check u r getting output is 2. But the third row contains 6 cells